# Use python selenium on headless linux server

Tags: python, linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver, headless-browser

I have a Linux server which can only be controlled via CLI.
It doesn't have any browser installed, mainly because it is not needed and because unless it's lynx or a derivative, it is going to install x-server, which I don't want.

I know I can run Chrome and Firefox with the headless option, but it still requires to be installed.

Is there any way I can run selenium on that server without having to install one of the "main" browsers, or will I have to switch to another library (urllib, requests) if I want to programatically browse the web?

Comment: if dynamic page use selenium + browser else beautifulsoup.

Comment: You can run [selenium in a docker container](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium)

Comment: I believe phantomJS doesn't require X, but the others do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use phantomJS which is headless-selenium for your purpose.

Download phantomJS

```
wget https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
```

Untar it

```
tar xvjf phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
```

Move or copy it into the binary executable directory

```
cp phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /usr/bin/
```

import the selenium webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
wd = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

connect to the website

```
wd.get("https://www.website-url.com")
```

Comment: phantomjs is no longer maintained ad deprecated within selenium

Comment: your example never uses chrome_options it creates

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg I know it has been deprecated but the OP wanted solution that could solve his problem for now. The solution is correct anyways. If the solution does not meet expectation in the long run does that mean you will downvote it?? In that case you should downvote all python 2 solution of problems.

Comment: it was deprecated long before the question was asked

Comment: I have used PhantomJS, but as @CoreyGoldberg stated, it's been long deprecated and is unmantained. In the end I used a regular browser and installed X. Thanks anyway for the solution.

Comment: Hamperfait I also have a solution using headless chrome. Reply if you need that.